# Intermediate value property under some conditions imply continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the intermediate value property.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose to each sequence $ (x_n) $ converging to $x$ there exists a constant $M$ such that
$$|f(x) - f(x_n)| ≤M \sup _{m}|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|$$
Then show that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Suppose that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that given $\delta>0$ there exists $y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ with $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon$.

In particular, given $n$, there exists $x_n$ such that $|x_n-x|<\frac{1}{n}$ with $|f(x_n)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon$.

So, we have the convergence $(x_n)\rightarrow x$. So, i can use the property that $$|f(x) - f(x_n)| \leq M \sup _{m}|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|$$

So, we have $$\epsilon\leq |f(x) - f(x_n)| ≤M \sup _{m}|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|$$

In particular,  $$\epsilon/M\leq  \sup _{m}|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|$$

I am stuck at this point.. I have no idea how to make use of intermediate value property of $f$..

Please give some hints.

Comment: What does $\sup \limits_m M|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|$ mean? The supremum certainly does not range over every integer $m$ because $\inf \limits_n \sup \limits_m |f(x_n) - f(x_m)| \geq \frac{|f(x_0) - f(x_1)|}{2}$.

Comment: I do not understand your comment..

Comment: I am asking of which set $\sup \limits_m M|f(x_n) - f(x_m)|$ is the supremum. It can't be $\sup(\{M|f(x_n) - f(x_m)| \ | \ m \in \mathbb{N}\})$ because then for most maps $f$ and sequences $(x_n)$, this has a strictly positive lower bound $a$ independant of $n$, so the condition holds trivially, taking $M$ to be greater than $\frac{\sup\{|f(x) - f(x_n)| \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\})}{a}$. Or maybe I am missing the point.

Comment: Fix $n$ and then take supremum over all $m\in \mathbb{N}$.. Please give some example where you think this might be of no use or go wrong.. @nombre

Comment: I thought $f(x) = (2x-1)\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ was a counter example but it turns out it doesn't satisfy the condition because you can find sequences $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)$ is constant but not $0$. So the statement might be true after all.

Comment: @nombre : It is true i believe.. .

Comment: Yes, to prove it, consider a subsequence $(y_n)$ of your sequence $(x_n)$ all of whose terms are greater than $f(x) + \varepsilon$ or lower than $f(x) - \varepsilon$, and find points $z_n \in \widetilde{[y_n;x]}$ such that $f(z_n) = f(x) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ in the first case, $f(z_n) = f(x) - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ in the second one. I live it to you to prove this using IVT and to see how it contradicts the condition with the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \sin \frac{1}{x} & x\ne 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{matrix}\right.$

This function is known for breaking thinks.

$f(x)$ is not continuous at $0$.  Yet does this function not satisfy all of the criteria?

Comment: I some how not able to bring all the statements together.. I am getting confused.. Please consider editing this..

Comment: Okay, complete change of direction...

Comment: It doesn't, for the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$ for instance.